# Visual Studio Code - custom command to undo changes on a single line

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

Is there a way to program a command in VS Code to undo unsaved (or uncommitted) changes to only the line that the cursor is on?

Sometimes I find myself only wanting to undo certain changes I made, but there are subsequent edits after the change that needs to be undone that I want to keep.  So <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> doesn't help because it would also undo changes that need to be kept.